# How can I see the assembly code that is generated by a gcc (any flavor) compiler for a C/C++ program?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, code-generation

I am trying to optimize a lot of multiplications and pointer arithmetics and would like to see what the compiler does underneath when I put in optimization flags.

**--Edit--**

How to restrict it to a specific function or a code block?

**--Edit_2--**

How to let gcc generate a less verbose assembly-code?

Comment: A less verbose assembly? What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: an assembly-code. In other words I dont want to extrenious things such as  initializations of activation records, but only the code relavent to my statemetns. hope it makes it clearer.

Comment: so you want gcc to generate _incorrect_ assembly code, that only satisfies your sence of beauty?  No, sir.

Comment: LOL I want to generate a correct one, but to display it a concise one for me. Is that too much to ask? No big deal though, extra info won't kill me. I was just wondering if it possible at all, or there are tools available.....  Pavel, I don't think you understand my question entirely

Comment: It is a bit much to ask, yes. The assembly it generates is precisely the code that the CPU will execute. If you need it to only show you the code that is relevant to you, then write a simplified function that does that operation, compile it, and then view the assembly.

Comment: And of course, the whole notion of "the code for a specific function" doesn't exist anymore once an optimizer inlined, reordered, merged and/or eliminated assembly instructions.

Comment: Have you played around with https://godbolt.org/ ? You should check it out.

Answer (score 42):

Add `-S` switch to your command line.

Edit: Do not forget that it will place the assembly to the files you specified under `-o` switch.

Comment: You can use `gcc -O3 -march=native foo.c   -S -o-  | less` to pipe into `less` instead of creating a `.s` file.  See also [How to remove “noise” from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output) for more tips about seeing the "interesting part" of the asm output, especially **Matt Godbolt's CppCon2017 talk: [“What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid”](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4)**

Answer (score 9):

> How to restrict it to a specific function or a code block?

Put that function in a separate source file (and use a different command-line parameter for that one source file).

Comment: That's what I have been doing. I am curious if it's possible from just options.

Comment: This may not reflect how it's really optimized if it can inline into callers.  (Especially with link-time optimization).  Having even one parameter be a compile-time constant can make a big difference, or having the alignment or size of an array known can change auto-vectorization a lot.  But yes, this is good *if* you understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 5):

You could also run that program in a debugger like `gdb` and use a disassembly view. In `gdb` you could use the command `disass/m` to view the assembly mixed with the C code on the current location.

Comment: Can you add a minimal example? `disass/m` just prints `No frame selected.`

Answer (score 3):

You could stop you program at a breakpoint in the Visual Studio debugger and do "show assembly" and even step through it one instruction at a time.

Comment: Why was this response down-voted? It is a perfectly valid response.

Comment: @aaronsnoswell I didn't do it, but presumably because the question is explicitly about GCC.