# HOW can i convert compiled program (hex) to code line?

Tags: c, mikroc

I have only a compiled binary code (.hex) of pic microcontroller,how can i convert it to code line in mikroc in order to see the instruction of program?

Comment: There isn't a reliable way to recover the source code used to create an executable.  I'm tolerably certain this has been asked and answered before.

Comment: You can disassemble it, You can probably decompile it into.. something not very useful.  As @JonathanLeffler says, this must have been asked before...

Comment: You might want to check http://boomerang.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/7798923/694576 if not a duplicate.

Comment: Disassembling without the licence is illegal as I know :)

Comment: A common term for this is "turning hamburger back into cows." There are tools that can convert machine code into the equivalent C source, but it won't be the *original* source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it's compiled, it is *machine code* and there's no (automatic) way of translating machine code to C. You *can* get a readable version of the code, *assembly*, using a *disassembler* for your target CPU. This of course requires you learning your CPU's assembly language.

Comment: ... and after having understood the assembler code, then rewrite the line of C code yourself. ;-)

Comment: @alk ...which will usually take longer than to write your own version from the scratch :)